# Using DTOs within the Hot Chocolate framework (using EFCore)

Tags: entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

We are using EF Core within the Hot Chocolate framework to access some SQL databases.
To overcome the issue with computed fields (described [here](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/2365)) we make use of DTOs.

This works perfectly fine in the example below. When querying for "Foo", the "GetFoo" method is called which created a "fooDTO" object with the computed parameter.

```cs
[UseProjection]
[UseFiltering]
[UseSorting]
public IQueryable<fooDTO> GetFoo([Service] ApiDbContext context) {
    return context.fooSet.AsEnumerable().Select(f => CreateFooDTO(f)).AsQueryable();
}

private static fooDTO CreateFooDTO(foo f){
    return new fooDTO{
        param1 = f.param1,
        param2 = f.param2,
        computedParam3 = param2 - param1,
        };
}
```

However, things go wrong when we want use DTOs when querying for "Bar" referring "Foo":

```json
{
   bar {
      foo
   }
}
```

For that case we provided the following methods:

```cs
[UseProjection]
[UseFiltering]
[UseSorting]
public IQueryable<barDTO> GetBar([Service] ApiDbContext context){
    return context.barSet.AsEnumerable().Select(b => CreateBarDTO(b)).AsQueryable();
}

private static barDTO CreateBarDTO(bar b){
    return new barDTO{
        param1 = b.param1,
        param2 = b.param2,
        param3 = CreateFooDTO(b.foo)
    };
}
```

Here "b.foo" seems to be always null, meaning that fooDTO is never materialized.

My questions:

- Is this problem related to Hot Chocolate or EF Core?
- How to properly use DTOs in this case?

Comment: I think the issue is how you are transforming the entities into DTOs. I would recommend an approach that does the actual work through the `IQueryable` such as AutoMapper's `ProjectTo`. For the computed value (foo.computedParam3) I would consider leaving this an ignored Getter that simply does the computation: ` public int computedParam3 { get { return param2 - param1; } }` telling AutoMapper to ignore that property.

Answer (score 2):

You have several choices here, using Automapper and it's `ProjectTo` or using libraries which helps in such case.

I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). It needs just configuring `DbContextOptions`:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Since EF Core can work only with ExpressionTree, you have to pass this tree to LINQ query somehow. `LINQKit` has ability to mark methods and their Expression analogue together. Then during expanding it will inject needed parts during query translation.

Assuming that you have configured your DbContext to use `LINQKit`, you can extend your methods with ExpressionTree versions via `ExpandableAttribute`:

```cs
[Expandable(nameof(CreateBarDTOmpl))]
public static barDTO CreateBarDTO(bar b)
{
    throw new NotImplementedExpeption()
}

private static Expression<Func<bar, barDTO>> CreateBarDTOmpl()
{
    return b => new barDTO
    {
        param1 = b.param1,
        param2 = b.param2,
        param3 = CreateFooDTO(b.foo)
    };
}

[Expandable(nameof(CreateFooDTOImpl))]
public static fooDTO CreateFooDTO(foo f)
{
   throw new NotImplementedExpeption()
}

private static Expression<Func<foo, fooDTO>>fooDTO CreateFooDTOImpl()
{
    return f => new fooDTO
    {
        param1 = f.param1,
        param2 = f.param2,
        computedParam3 = f.param2 - f.param1,
    };
}
```

Then usage is simple:

```cs
[UseProjection]
[UseFiltering]
[UseSorting]
public IQueryable<fooDTO> GetFoo([Service] ApiDbContext context) 
{
    return context.fooSet.Select(f => CreateFooDTO(f));
}
```

It will generate the same projection as Automapper's `ProjectTo` but without configuring mapping. Later you may find how it useful to simplify a lot of similar predicates or other repetitive LINQ query parts.